# Dropbox folder not syncing after move

Tags: finder, macos, dropbox

I moved my dropbox folder to a different location, following the instructions provided by dropbox. (I use the desktop client. `OS X 10.11.5`)

Specifically, I clicked on the Dropbox icon, went to Preferences -> Account, and changed Dropbox location. It took a while to copy the files. Now, for some weird reason, most of my files are stuck in 'syncing'. I don't understand why it has to sync anything at all, since the files were copied within the hard drive, and no file was modified in the cloud.

It's been stuck at `6,990 files` remaining for the last two hours. When I move the mouse over the dropbox logo, it says `Indexing 6,990 files` and `Can't sync "x (Access Denied)`. What does this even mean? There are shared folders in my dropbox that I need to use right now. What do I do?

Comment: I'd guess you just have to wait it out. It's the kind of task you should leave for overnight.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue is with the fact that I moved my dropbox folder to an external drive. In that case, OSX creates a bunch of files named `._filename`, which dropbox cannot sync. To clean these files, [someone wrote this small script](https://github.com/simsalabim/dsweeper) that works in the background. I installed and ran it, and my problems were solved.

Comment: OSX does not do that if on HFS+ but only if a non Apple filesystem